# Angular multiple form JSON at same object with different dynamic array index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have multiple form can be more than 5-10 that should be posted in JSON format in which index be created dynamically also with nested JSON array. If possible provide with examples.

Angular code

```
$scope.userForm = {};

//parentForm
//single element
input[ng-model="userForm.parent.parentName"]

//child form
//this element can be multiple user can add multiple record
input[ng-model="userForm.child.childName"]

//sub child form
//this element can be multiple user can add multiple record
input[ng-model="userForm.subChild.subChildName"]
```

After submitting form I got the result

```
/*{
    "parent":{
        "parentName": "nameValue"
    },
    "child":{
        "childName": "nameValue"
    },
    "subChild":{
        "subChildName": "nameValue"
    }
}*/
```

What is the best way to get such output without using push method? because there are lots of form with different array index

```
/*{
    "parent":{
        "parentName": "nameValue"
    },
    "child":[{
        "childName": "nameValue"
    },{
        "childName": "nameValue"
    },{
        "childName": "nameValue"
    }],
    "subChild":[{
        "subChildName": "nameValue"
    },{
        "subChildName": "nameValue"
    }]
}*/
```

Comment: How you know wich parent have wich childrens?

Comment: first step in angular i have create empty object that is userForm.
in ng-model i have define the parent with child like userForm.parent.name.
which will output {"parent': {"name": "value"}}.